# How to split array of numbers to two array by equal total sum

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const arrOfNumbers = [1,2,4,7,4,10,8,2,3,4,6,8,5,2];
// note numbers in array can be created randomly
const splitted1 = [];
const splitted2 = [];


function splitArray(arr){
  const tmpArr = arr.filter(
    (num) => ![...splitted1, ...splitted2].some((p) => num === p)
  );

  const minNum = Math.min.apply(
    Math,
    tmpArr
  );

  let newNum;
  if (splitted1.length > 0)
    newNum = tmpArr.find((t) => t === splitted1[splitted1.length - 1]);

  if (splitted1.length > splitted2.length && newNum) {
    splitted2.push(newNum);
  } else {
    newNum = tmpArr.find((p) => p === minNum);
    if (splitted1.length === splitted2.length) {
      splitted1.push(newNum);
    } else {
      splitted2.push(newNum);
    }
  }

  if (tmpArr.length > 1) splitArray(tmpArr);

}

splitArray(arrOfNumbers);

console.log(splitted1, splitted2);
```

I need to split array of numbers to two arrays which is equal of sum.
I've tried find numbers by minimum and add each array once but it not works.

How can I split it equally and if its not possible split by equal total sum then split with minimum difference

```
const arrOfNumbers = [1,2,4,7,4,10,8,2,3,4,6,8,5,2];
// note numbers in array can be created randomly
const splitted1 = [];
const splitted2 = [];


function splitArray(arr){
  const tmpArr = arr.filter(
    (num) => ![...splitted1, ...splitted2].some((p) => num === p)
  );

  const minNum = Math.min.apply(
    Math,
    tmpArr
  );

  let newNum;
  if (splitted1.length > 0)
    newNum = tmpArr.find((t) => t === splitted1[splitted1.length - 1]);

  if (splitted1.length > splitted2.length && newNum) {
    splitted2.push(newNum);
  } else {
    newNum = tmpArr.find((p) => p === minNum);
    if (splitted1.length === splitted2.length) {
      splitted1.push(newNum);
    } else {
      splitted2.push(newNum);
    }
  }

  if (tmpArr.length > 1) splitArray(tmpArr);

}

splitArray(arrOfNumbers)

// splitted1 [1,2,3,4,4,6,10] total sum 30
// splitted2 [2,2,2,4,5,8,7] total sum 30
// after splitting it should be
```

Comment: What's your expected output for the above? Can you give a few more input/output examples?

Comment: is every given array solvable? what if not? what if more than on result?

Comment: numbers in initial array can be generated randomly between 1 and 10, and length must be 14, and I need to divide it to two array with equal sum of numbers

Comment: What do you do with this where the total is 15? [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2]

Comment: actually it can be array of objects with unique id and number comparsion will be made by id